# Requirements for std::thread::id. Can it be atomized?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, language-lawyer

The standard says: "An object of type thread::id provides... a single distinct value for all thread objects that do not represent a thread of execution". Is that a single/distinct value with regard to `operator==`, or is it the actual bitwise-single/distinct value?

The reason for the question: MSVC2012's `std::thread::id::id()` leaves garbage in one of its fields, and it breaks code that does compare-exchange on an `std::atomic<std::thread::id>` (since the latter depends on bitwise comparisons).

Is `std::atomic<std::thread::id>` a legal construct in the first place?

EDIT: for the reference, the code goes like this:

```
while( !worker_id.compare_exchange_weak( no_id = thread_id_type(), self_id ) )
    sleep();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, `std::atomic<std::thread::id>` is legal: `std::thread::id` is required to be trivially copyable (30.3.1.1p2), which meets the requirements of `std::atomic<>` (29.5p1).

However, it is an opaque class, so there is no requirement that the bit pattern of objects that compare equal be identical.

Consequently, if you use `compare_exchange_weak` or `compare_exchange_strong` then it may fail for values that compare equal.

Thus, the advice is to use `compare_exchange_weak` in a loop, **leaving the `expected` value as the result of the previous iteration**.

In your case, the semantics I interpret from your loop are: keep looping whilst `worker_id` is the ID of another thread, or `worker_id` was `std::thread::id` but the exchange failed. You can achieve this with the following:

```
no_id=std::thread::id();
while((no_id!=std::thread::id()) ||
      !worker_id.compare_exchange_weak( no_id, self_id ) ){
    if(no_id!=std::thread::id()) no_id=std::thread::id();
    sleep();
}
```

or

```
no_id=std::thread::id();
while(!worker_id.compare_exchange_weak(
          (no_id!=std::thread::id())?(no_id=std::thread::id())?no_id, self_id ) )
    sleep();
```

i.e. only change the `no_id` value if it is **not** `std::thread::id()`.

Comment: Thank you. Selectively resetting `no_id` is a nice trick, now I'm beginning to wonder why I didn't see it :)

Comment: But you probably would only want to call sleep if "no_id!= std::thread::id()" in the loop.

Comment: @cmeerw Yes --- I was just trying to replicate vpozdyayev's loop as closely as possible. If `compare_exchange_weak` fails "spuriously" then you in most cases you want to loop immediately, without waiting.

Answer (score 5):

This was discussed in [LWG924](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2992.htm#LWG924). Essentially, you can't use `compare_exchange_strong`, but you should be able to use compare_exchange_weak in a loop, e.g.

```
expected = current.load();
do {
  desired = function(expected);
} while (!current.compare_exchange_weak(expected, desired));
```

**Edit**: Unconditionally resetting the value defeats the purpose of the loop - based on the supplied code, I think the best solution would then be:

```
no_id = std::thread::id();
while( !worker_id.compare_exchange_weak( no_id, self_id ) )
{
  if (no_id != std::thread::id())
  {
    sleep();
    no_id = std::thread::id();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using `compare_exchange_weak` in a loop and, sadly, it doesn't help. BTW, the issue here is uninitialized fields, not padding (mentioned as a "related but separable issue" in your link). I'm aware of the note 29.6.5/26 about memcmp semantics and compare_exchange_weak converging rapidly, but I still don't see how it could possibly work if `current` and `expected` are bitwise-different representations of the same (as per `operator==`) value.